# Better option to get time in hh:mm format from two given time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, time

```
select cast(datediff(minute,convert(time,'09:35 AM'),
       convert(time,'07:06 PM'))/60 as varchar)
       +':'+cast(datediff(minute,convert(time,'09:35 AM'),
       convert(time,'07:06 PM'))%60 as varchar)
```

**Output** : `9:31`

Do we have any other function by which I can shorten the above script. Also, what should I do to get output as `09:31` instead of `9:31` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`CONVERT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187928.aspx) with style 114 to get the `HH:mm`

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(5), 
        -- Get difference of time
        CONVERT(datetime,'07:06 PM') - CONVERT(datetime,'09:35 AM')
        , 114)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1222)

**EDIT**

As comment to avoid the datetime arithmetic

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), 
        DATEADD(minute, 
            DATEDIFF(minute, convert(time,'09:35 AM'), convert(time,'07:06 PM')) 
        , 0)
    , 114)
```

Comment: [Avoid using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function in Sql Server.

**Update - (Example)** : this may be what you want:

```
select FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime,'9:31'),'HH:mm') AS 'time'
```

Comment: That version of `FORMAT` was only introduced in SQL Server 2012. The question is listed under sql-server-2008.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @time1 AS VARCHAR(8) = '09:35 AM'
DECLARE @time2 AS VARCHAR(8) = '07:06 PM'
    
SELECT 
    time1   = CAST(@time1 AS TIME), 
    time2   = CAST(@time2 AS TIME),
    diff    = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @time1, @time2),
    hh      = RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(@time1 AS TIME), CAST(@time2 AS TIME))/60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2),
    mm      = RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(@time1 AS TIME), CAST(@time2 AS TIME))%60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2),
    final   = RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(@time1 AS TIME), CAST(@time2 AS TIME))/60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
              RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(@time1 AS TIME), CAST(@time2 AS TIME))%60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

When declaring and/or converting to a `VARCHAR` type, you should specify the length, otherwise SQL-Server will assign a default value for you. Sometimes it's `1`, other times it's `30`. See this [**article**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) for more information.

Also to format the difference into `hh:mm`, you need to pad your strings with the appropriate number of zero. This is done using :

```
RIGHT('00' + str, 2)
```

Comment: it seems my query looks shorter than your :)

Comment: Yes, but that does not mean your's is better. Shorter does not always equate to shorter.  I just corrected your `VARCHAR` conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this ad check if this is what you want:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'hh:mm')
```

OR

```
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 114))
```